# Drupal 7 Apache Solr Search module custom ordering of results

Tags: search

I've been stuck on how, if its even possible to meet a certain search criteria that's been set. This is it:

The user enters keyword "george" Search rules: Top to Bottom sorting

A. All advanced profiles with “George” in title

B. All basic profiles with “George” in title

C. All advanced profiles with “George” in body text

d. All basic profiles with “George” in body text

The basic/advance option comes from a boolean value set in the node.

So its sorting within sorting or conditional boosting. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks